# Is it correct to retag questions that fit in my recently created tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just created the [convert-tz](/questions/tagged/convert-tz) tag in Stack OverFlow. I think it can be useful when talking about MySQL and the data conversion depending on timezone.

I do not want to push to make my tag *useful*, but at the same time I think it can be somehow good. I retag some questions but then stopped to check if I am doing something wrong.

So, is it correct and friendly enough to retag other questions that could fit in this tag?

Comment: I would suggest that you update the tag-wiki so it is clear what this tag is to be used for [Convert-TZ Tag Wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/convert-tz/info).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other questions clearly are *about* using `CONVERT_TZ` in the context of MySQL, then adding the tag to other questions would certainly help define the reach of the tag for others.

I'd say go ahead and use it where appropriate.

Do also submit a [tag wiki text](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/convert-tz/info) for your tag, describing what the tag is about (make sure you use original content, don't just copy-paste).